# Express $27\cdot16^{11}+16^7+33\cdot16^4-16^4$ as a hexadecimal number

Tags: number-systems

Question:
Express $$\large27\cdot16^{11}+16^7+33\cdot16^4-16^4$$  as a hexadecimal number.

Comment: what does $\times$ mean? or is that a $x$?

Comment: is this $$27\cdot 16^{11}+16^7+33\cdot 16^4-16^4$$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! In Math.SE, while asking questions, please tell what you tried and where you're stuck, this'll encourage others to help you, otherwise your question may be flagged and closed.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes

Comment: too late the answer is given alrady

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$27(16^{11})+(16^7)+33(16^4)-(16^4)$$
$$=16(16^{11})+11(16^{11})+(16^7)+33(16^4)-(16^4)$$
$$=(16^{12})+11(16^{11})+(16^7)+33(16^4)-(16^4)$$
$$=(16^{12})+11(16^{11})+(16^7)+32(16^4)$$
$$=(16^{12})+11(16^{11})+(16^7)+2(16)(16^4)$$
$$=(16^{12})+11(16^{11})+(16^7)+2(16^5)$$
$$=1B00010200000_{16}$$